# ssh key order changing

Tags: ssh, putty, pageant

I use pam_ssh_agent_auth for authorising
And also use  id_rsa.pub for authorising between servers

And today I found problem - when I try to `svn update` , I can't do it, because my svn use ssh+svn:// - so it first makes ssh tunnel then connect to svn server...
But it use my putty key instead of id_rsa.pub....

When I turn off pageant - svn is working as expected.

Is there a way to set order of using keys - now first checking is pageant, if not satisfied it use `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. How to reverse it?

Comment: Have you try to add id_rsa to agent too?

Comment: SVN + SSH should honour the [`~/.ssh/config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)  file  (i.e. `/root/.ssh/config` when you're running as root)  where you can specify which identity file should be used for your SVN host in a Host block with `IdentityFile`   in combination with `IdentitiesOnly` if needed

Comment: Why not just put into authorized_keys all the keys you can connect to the server with?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov because there are different permissions for server key and my own key.

Comment: @HBruijn - Both ways uses this file. So it isn't solution